# Is it possible to make a Social Sign Up with Twitter Account?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, hybridauth

I am using *HybridAuth* on my project and added *Facebook*, *Twitter* and *LinkedIn* social providers in order for the user to be able to sign up/ sign in. 
What I have encountered is that *Twitter API* does not return the users' email. Thus the user obviously can't sign up with his *Twitter* account.

Furthermore if the user has logged out - he can't even sign in with his *Twitter* account if he hasn't connected it to your application account, because the *Twitter API* won't use the email for searching the user in its' database. In order to be able to use *Twitter* Sign In, the user has to be signed in to your app and connect his *Twitter* account.

Is there anything I am missing and there is an actual way to Sign Up with *Twitter*?